# Parse signed Byte from binary | Java

Tags: java, binary, byte, numberformatexception

I have the following problem in Java. I am using an encryption algorithm that can produce negative bytes as outcome, and for my purposes I must be able to deal with them in binary. For negative bytes, the first or most significant bit in the of the 8 is 1. When I am trying to convert binary strings back to bytes later on, I am getting a `NumberFormatException` because my byte is too long. Can I tell Java to treat it like an unsigned byte and end up with negative bytes? My code so far is this:

```java
private static String intToBinByte(int in) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("00000000");
        sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(in));
        return sb.substring(sb.length() - 8);
}
```

```java
intToBinByte(-92); // --> 10100100
Byte.parseByte("10100100", 2) // --> NumberFormatException
```

```
Value out of range. Value:"10100100" Radix:2
```

Is there a better way to parse **signed** Bytes from binary in Java?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the following function to solve the problem:

```java
private static byte binStringToByte(String in) {
    byte ret = Byte.parseByte(in.substring(1), 2);
    ret -= (in.charAt(0) - '0') * 128;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just parse it with a larger type, then cast it to byte.  Casting simply truncates the number of bits:

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt("10100100", 2);
```